# Кнопка в Google Maps (Android)

Tags: java, android, google-maps-api

Хочу спросить, что это за кнопка в `Google Maps` слева? Знаю, что правая отвечает за Current Location. А как называется левая и как ее добавить на карту?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Это переход в полноэкранный режим

Comment: А как ее добавить на карту? Знаю, что правая кнопка добавляется одной строчкой кода mMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);

Comment: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-api/controls вот тут написано, что доступно из готового.

Comment: @iFr0z Спасибо!